# Problems in executing a query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this exception being thrown with mongodb connection

Wed May 11 10:39:33 Assertion: 10057:unauthorized for db [inbox] lock type: -1

where inbox is the database. I am using the PHP driver for the connection. The problem is I am using the admin username and password for the connection but still it is throwing unauthorized. Can you please provide some insights.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating as an admin requires you to run the authenticate command in the *admin* database before changing to the regular database.  Authenticating your admin user from say, *test* will not work.

For your case, connect to *admin*, run authenticate as the admin user, and then get a handle on *inbox*.  Alternately you should create a user specific to the *inbox* database for safety.  Connecting as a superuser for an application isn't the best idea.

Comment: No actually the problem is the error is random. Sometimes it is authenticating properly sometimes it isn't. I think authentication to a non admin database was supposed to work with the start of the php driver from 1.0.4 onwards. It was working properly but all of a sudden it has started showing this type of error.

Comment: This may be an issue best posted to the MongoDB-User mailing list for further diagnosis.